# Can one follow Rabbeinu Tam time for beginning Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, zemanim, candle-lighting, rabbeinu-tam

Does anyone today follow Rabbineu Tam time for the beginning of Shabbos? Reading some tshuvas (e.g. Eretz haTzvi) it is clear this was widespread in Europe.

If one has previously been accustomed to accept Shabbos according to the Gra/Baal HaTanya, can one switch to Rabbeinu Tam?

(In particular, if one is sure his ancestors did so in Europe, can one revive this minhag after it fell into disuse after migrating to America?)

Comment: There are several distinct questions here. In the first part, are you looking for whether one is permitted to follow Rabenu Tam or precedent for doing so?

Comment: @WAF: In the first part, I am looking for modern-day precedent. Then I am looking for thoughts about the permissibility of switching. And finally thoughts about whether one's past family minhag should be relevant to the permissibility.

Comment: I've been in several chassidishe communities around the world.  In Israel, everyone both stops melacha, and prays Friday afternoon minchah, before sunset.  In the US and Europe, they stop doing melacha before sunset, but will wait to pray minchah until as much as 58 minutes after sunset.  Usually, it's a bit earlier, like 40 minutes after sunset, when there's still a little light in the sky in the Northeast US, or Northern Europe.

Comment: I know of a modern American Jewish community that follows Rabbeinu Tam. I don't know what their justification is. Their orientation is shomer mitzvos, with people ranging in observance from Conservative/OO to liberal Chasidic.

Comment: @SAH Do they follow his time on both ends of Shabbat, or just the beginning?

Comment: @DoubleAA Just the end, B"H. (Although there are some people in this community who do it on both ends in their personal observance.)

Comment: "it is clear this was widespread in Europe" This is a misconception. It was widespread to do work after viewed sunset, but no one ever ever ever followed RT's time to allow work 58 minutes after sunset (and all the moreso not a latitude adjusted 58 minutes either). People worked for maybe 20 minutes after viewed sunset.

Answer (score 5):

I have no source, but have heard that when *Rav Yoel* of *Satmar* came to America, he and his followers did follow *Rabenu Tam*. *Rav Moshe* Feinstein, the story goes, asked him if he could desist, explaining that Americans would follow his own view for the end of *Shabas* and *Rav Yoel*'s for the start, and *Rav Yoel* agreed to.

Comment: I did find a note in the Divrei Yoel which indicates that one should fulfill the time of the Gaonim for accepting Shabbos (http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20289&st=&pgnum=122) but this contradicts what everyone seems to know about Satmar?

Comment: The note in Divrei Yoel is to follow the Gaonim lachumra only, see above.  what "everyone seems to know about Satmar" is a mistake, no satmar chosid will now drive after sunset.

Comment: @Philomath: Thanks -- is there any discussion anywhere of when this decision was made? Is it true that Satmar still do melacha in private up until RT time? Any sources would be great.

Comment: @Curiouser: I have found a copy of the _kol koira_ here [link](http://www.ivelt.com/forum/download/file.php?id=16849&sid=4ef808c9717b541cd5ac41e5c1e9ce87&mode=view), it mentions the date the decision was taken, which is 7 April 1954 in civil date.   the minhag of satmar chasidim today in private _b'shas hadchak_ is not quite clear (as well as the _da'as_ of Rav Yoel himself). see here [link](http://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=9958) for a great discussion among satmar chasidim themselves, it's in Yiddish though.

Comment: FWIW _Rav Yoel_ immigrated in 1946 (apparently).

Comment: @msh210: that's right, Rav Yoel's ship anchored at the NY port the first day of _Rosh Hashana_ 5707, which is 26 September 1946 civil date. He was machmir not to leave the ship until after _Yom Tov_.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the influence of the Vilna Gaon and subsequent *poskim*, the absolutely normative practice for mainstream Ashkenazim in North America is that Shabbos starts at sunset. Barring particularly unusual circumstances, that is our halachic norm and should be followed. It is at the very least *minhag hamakom.*

"Revive the minhag" is not the appropriate language here, as it involves doing something that is considered a serious sin according to the norms the community here and now. I just don't hear it.

Comment: I was really looking for information about what might factor into this decision. For instance, when Satmar first arrived in America they would do melacha after sunset, following Rabbeinu Tam. Do they still? If not, what made them change? What were the considerations? Did the change have a status of a neder? Could they go back if they wanted to? Is following Rabbeinu Tam really considered a "serious sin"? Source? If true, then that would be a factor.

Comment: Curiouser, minhag America is that shabbos starts at sunset (or maybe in emergency situations, up to 13 minutes later); according to that minhag, doing work after that time is "a serious sin." It's not like a minhag of stand-or-sit at kiddush, where there's far less at stake.

Comment: Again, I appreciate that is your view, but I was really interested in sources on this topic (as is the usual custom on this site). If you have sources that discuss this or support your view, please share them. Obviously the Satmar chasidim who drove to shul after sunset were not committing a "serious sin", God forbid. I would be interested in sources that discuss the issue, the nature of the minhag, its malleability in light of the minhag of others, etc.

Comment: let's clear up a bit. first, there is no such thing as "*minhag america*", as there is a mix of *kahilos* coming from different places, (see *bava matzia* 83b). now, in Principe satmar still follows *Rabbineu Tam* time (which is, by the way, the da'as of most rishonim), as the *minhag* was in Europe. but to prevent *machlokos* (etc) Rav Yoel of Satmar called together 70-80 rabanim (most of them from Brooklyn), and they come to an agreement to follow both zmanim (Rabbineu Tam & geoinim) *lachumra* with regard to shabbos. this is well known to any satmar chosid.

Comment: @Shalom: it would be in context to add here Rav Meltzer's words [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40300&st=&pgnum=5) that now we all must be machmir l'shitas Rabbineu Tam _l'halacha_.

Comment: @Philomath, I respectfully disagree. R' Moshe Feinstein says that local customs are transplanted only when a community emigrates en-masse (as was the case with the Frankfurt community that relocated to Washington Heights, maintaining which family sat where in the synagogue!). When it's a group of individuals doing their own thing, then even if it now turns out that Anytown USA has 90% of its population from Hotzenplotz Poland, the customs of Hotzenplotz are not in force.

Comment: He also cites the Chavos Yair, that if when everyone left the old city they had no intention of ever returning (which wasn't the case during the Balance-of-Power system for centuries in Europe, but was the case with the Holocaust), the original locale's customs would be void even if people later returned. I maintain that several practices became strongly normative for the overwhelming majority of mainstream American Orthodoxy which become "minhag America" (Rabbi Wein has a tape on the subject), including starting Shabbos at sunset at the latest.

Comment: If you want to start an endless debate about *ending* Shabbos by Rabbeinu Tam's definition, please (don't) open a separate question about that. If it was 72 minutes in Provence what does that mean at other latitudes ... who says Rabbeinu Tam's 72 start at what we call sunset ... we can theorize and debate from today until tomorrow; for normative American practice, The Agudas HaRabbonim told people in New York to end Shabbos 42 minutes after sunset ... R' Moshe Feinstein 45 ... and others are machmir to 72.

Answer (score 1):

Yalqut Yosef - Qizur Shulhan `Arukh ([Orah Hayim 261:6](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_23.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%90B-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99B%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A7B%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94-%D7%95)) states (my translation):

> הדבר ברור שאין להקל ח''ו לעשות מלאכה אחר השקיעה שלנו, שכבר פשט המנהג כדעת הגאונים, וחס ושלום לפרוץ גדר ולהקל כשיטת רבינו תם, ורק לחומרא בצאת השבת אנו מחמירים כדעת רבינו תם.
>
> Clearly, there is no room to be lenient H"W to perform *melakhah* after our [definition of] sunset since the prevalent custom is per the opinion of the *Ge'onim*.
>
> And Heaven forbid one from being lenient per *Rabbe'inu Tam's* opinion - for it is only when being stringent at the end of Shabbat that we behave in accordance with [his opinion].

Answer (score 0):

Some hasidic groups still start Shabbat (and end Shabbat) according to Rabeinu Tam. I saw this with the hasidim in Lakewood, NJ and with Belz in Eretz Israel. A rabbi in the hasidic community in Lakewood told me that they, relying on Rabeinu Tam, will do melakhoth until about 30 minutes after Shekiah.

The Igros Moshe has a teshuba that permits if necessary doing melakhoth that are de'rabbanan during bein shemaot. Referenced here: 
"Tosefet Shabbat" – Adding Time Onto Shabbat
By Rav Yosef Tzvi Rimon
Translated by David Silverberg
Har Etzion Yeshiva

Comment: 30 minutes after sunset is not Rabbenu Tam...

Comment: @DoubleAA that’s true. R”T would be about 1 hour after sunset

Comment: So wouldn't it seem more likely they're following a different opinion that says "bein hashmashos" starts 30 minutes after sunset and "tzeit hakochavim" is ~15 minutes later? That would match the observable astronomic reality of when you could see stars in Europe and fit with what was the common custom there for when to start/end shabbos. The people back then weren't stupid; they could see when the stars came out.

Comment: @DoubleAA my impression is that they stop work 30 min before r”t being makhmir the same way that people stop working 18-30 min before sunset at candle lighting even though it’s well before sunset

Comment: But then why don't we see exceptions of working later just like nowadays when plenty plenty of people running late work into the 18 minutes? Chasam Sofer wrote a detailed teshuva ruling a baby boy born 27 minutes after sunset on Saturday should have his bris on next Shabbos; clearly it wasn't obvious that up to an hour is just a minhag for tosefes shabbos

Comment: Let's also remember that at those latitudes in Europe, their waiting 72 minutes would be about the same level of darkness as ~45 minutes in Israel, so it's highly debatable if they were following RT.

Comment: Interesting points. Someone told me that all the rishonim kept Shabbat starting at R”T and it was the vilna gaon that convinced others to start maintaining Shabbat starting at the current mainstream shekiah practice. If you could elaborate as to why or how this happened or substantiate this i think it would add a lot to this discussion

Comment: There's a lot to summarize here of course, but the short story is that while most Rishonim do write like Rabbenu Tam's explanation of the gemara (that dawn and tzeis are each the same 4 mil (as calculated in Israel at the equinox) from sunrise/sunset respectively) there's no evidence anyone, even Rabbenu Tam, ever practiced that way. They all appear to have begun day mitzvos when they could see some light and end shabbos when they saw a few stars, with bein hashemashos starting ~15 minutes before then, well after sunset by today's standards. (cont)

Comment: Almost no one had clocks or any precise time measuring device so why would you calculate tzes instead of looking outside? Only later with the dissemination of clocks in urban areas did anyone think to actually figure out the numbers and that's when you get works like Minchas Kohein in the 1600s noticing that the simple read of Rabbenu Tam's explanation of the gemara doesn't jive with reality. The Gra came up with a different explanation of the gemara and encouraged people to stop doing work immediately at sunset.

Comment: He said the Geonim agreed with him (which isn't an obvious claim; it's possible he was aware and advocated this to prevent people doing work too late on Fri based on applying RTs calculations to clocks). For whatever reason, people agreed to be strict from sunset like the Gra, but never changed when they finished shabbos, which is when stars are actually visible, well after what would follow from the Gra's explanation of the gemara. While the contradictions between RT's explanation and the realia are easier to spot, the Gra's explanation also doesn't neatly match the reality of stars in Israel

Comment: If you're familiar with the gemaras, remember RT said tzeis in pesachim is tzeis for shabbos, and shkiya in pesachim is a meaningless extra shkiya, while the gra says the opposite that shkiya in pesachim is shkiya for shabbos and tzeis in pesachim is a meaningless extra tzeis. Arguably, the Geonim and Rambam and Rashi and the old minhag was the middle option: tzeis and shkiya in pesachim are both meaningless and in between is shkiya for shabbos and tzeis for shabbos. There's no reason there can't be too shkiyas *and* two tzeises.

Comment: We have old shul bulletins from 200+ years ago in europe and they ended shabbos in some places even earlier than we do (we end about 8.5° below the horizon, they'd end at 7°-7.5°) but they did work after sunset. And they started dawn well before 7° in the morning so they weren't following Rabbenu Tam conceptually either that dawn to sunrise equals sunset to tzeis equals 4 mil. There must be a middle option.

Comment: Can you provide the citation for the Chatam Sofer on a bris born 27 minutes after shkiyah? Thanks! Also are those old shul bulletins something you are willing to share / upload?