# Do any Chasidim still accept Shabbos according to Rabbeinu Tam zman?

Tags: minhag, zemanim, chasidut-hasidism, leil-shabbat

Apparently there is a story that Rav Moshe Feinstein asked the Satmar Rebbe to not have his followers begin shabbos with zman Rabbeinu Tam. Is there still a minhag amongst chasidim to take on shabbos according to Rabbeinu Tam anywhere?

This is somewhat similar to [Can one follow Rabbeinu Tam time for beginning Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/can-one-follow-rabbeinu-tam-time-for-beginning-shabbos)

but here it is not about practical halacha for the 'hamon am', but specifically geared towards Chasidim and current practices.

Comment: A friend of mine met a satmer guy in a hospital cooking after sunset because he felt Rav Moshes request didn't apply since he wasn't in a community. This is a few years ago and he was in the NYC metropolitan area.

Comment: Yes I also understand that satmar  only in public or when there is no need  they take in shabos by like the rest of the jews

Comment: @hazoriz that might be the normative American community, this question is assuming as much with regards to them

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat complicated, but in a limited sense you can see it in Boropark. It's not necessarily community sanctioned, and for the most part outward obvious deoraisas such as driving and smoking cease by candlelighting or at the latest by standard shkia  time, but on an individual basis, you will see people who don't use the eiruv carrying in the street, or they'll squeeze water out of their peyos after the mikva, and things like that.

But I do know that many if not all Chassidim do use Rabbeinu Tam's shkia for other halachos like mila and nidda so their not relying on it erev shabbos is a chumra in their eyes, not ikkur din.

And as for the story you quoted with Reb Moshe, I've heard the same scenario between the Satmar Rabbe and Reb Aharon in Lakewood, so I don't put too much faith in either version being true.

Answer (score 0):

Some hasidic groups still start Shabbat (and end Shabbat) according to Rabeinu Tam. I saw this with the hasidim in Lakewood, NJ and with Belz in Eretz Israel. A rabbi in the hasidic community in Lakewood told me that they, relying on Rabeinu Tam, will do melakhoth until about 30 minutes after Shekiah.

The Igros Moshe has a teshuba that permits if necessary doing melakhoth that are de'rabbanan during bein shemaot. Referenced here: "Tosefet Shabbat" – Adding Time Onto Shabbat By Rav Yosef Tzvi Rimon Translated by David Silverberg Har Etzion Yeshiva

Comment: 30 minutes after sunset is not Rabbenu Tam...