# Lighting Shabbat candles after shekiya

Tags: shabbat

It is well known that people lighto shabbas candles before(many are careful to light 18-20 minutes before) shikya and no later. However, the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 75:1 holds one has until 30 minutes before the emergence of 3 medium stars. So in a pressing situation why cant one hold like the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch? I have seen poskim who write that after shekiya it is forbidden  (Mishna Brurah) and discuss if a non-Jew can light in their stead (Biur Halacha).

Comment: Why be meikil on an issur skila for a mitzvah derabanan?

Comment: I am unaware where the Kitzur gets hisbtime from ,but it could be there are others who hold the same,so he may nkg be a daas yachid,even so a daas yachid in a shas hadchak might be fine,its a big machkokes

Comment: My point is its not so dechak. Its not so big a deal to miss lighting

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8778 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66282. Also somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62304.

Comment: I understand that but adding an additional light is not pleasant, not the greatest feeling for a woman

Comment: @sam You know what else is not pleasant? Death by stoning. If you want to be meikil on something, be meikil on the custom to add extra candles.

Comment: Isn't possible that a lot of people follow the Kitsur SA? Why are you persued that everybody follows the Mishna Berura?

Answer (score 0):

There are two shkias - the regular shkia and Rabbeinu Tam's shkia, which is 58.5 minutes after the regular shkia. Since we are dealing with a safek issur kares, you must be stringent and therefore you may not light candles even a millisecond after the regular shkia, and to do so is a safek issur kares.

Comment: I believe you are on the right track, namely: 1) The *Kitzur* appears to follow both the stringencies and leniencies of Rabbeinu Tam, which is not the common practice nowadays. 2) According to the many rishonim and geonim whose opinions we generally follow on this issue nowadays, it is biblically forbidden to light candles after what we usually call *sh'kiya*, i.e. visible sunset. However, your answer could use some detail to explain these matters and elaborate on why it's inappropriate to follow *Kitzur* in this case.