# Z'man of Rabbeinu Tam - when does science determine a psak?

Tags: zemanim, evening-night, vilna-gaon, geonim, rabbeinu-tam

I recently read a very well-researched sefer about the machlokes Rabbeinu Tam and the Gaonim about when is tzeis hakochavim: When does halachic night begin, 72 minutes after sunset or when the sun gets a certain angle below the horizon? The sefer is, *[The Great Z'manim Debate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1957579129)*, by Rabbi Aharon Notis. I knew a lot of the astronomy, but he did a very good job of presenting exactly how different parts of the astronomical issues play a role in helping decide various parts of the halachic issues. Alos hashachar, tzeis, shaos zmanios according to the Vilna Gaon and Magen Avraham...
The author of the sefer has a very clear point of view, roughly described by a quote he brings (p. 179) from Rav Yisrael Yaakov Fisher z"l of Yerushalayim. He was asked by a talmid chacham from Lakewood why he is not machmir for Rabbeinu Tam's opinion at all - even for Shabbos or Yom Kippur. Rav Fisher answered, "Rabbeinu Tam was shlugged up."
In other words, the author holds (along w Rav Fisher and I guess the Vilna Gaon), that since the astronomical understanding clearly proves that the opinion the Gaonim is correct, and that Rabbeinu Tam is wrong, we do not need to take Rabbeinu Tam into account at all.
Note that this is even though many Rishonim held like Rabbeinu Tam, including many Ba'alei Tosefos, the Ramban, the Shulchan Aruch and Rema - and many Acharonim. The author and these poskim understand that scientific proof is different than halachic understanding; once the science is settled, the halachic issue is completely settled as well.

So my question: Let us *assume* that the science here is completely settled, that we know for sure that the Gaonim (and other Rishonim like the Rambam and others) are absolutely correct on the science. *Assuming* that is so, does it settle the halachic issue? Or are there poskim who hold, "We don't have a Sanhedrin yet, and any p'sak by the Shulchan Aruch is going to be binding until we do. Whatever the reason they decided, we cannot ignore their p'sak no matter what we know to be true, for they have authority and we do not." Something like that.
[This is not exactly the same question as what to do about בעי כינים, because (a) that is a p'sak of the Gemara, not Rishonim, which lends it more authority, and (b) there we don't know for sure what the gemara is saying, only how some Rishonim understood it. One can try to find new ways to understand the gemara. Again, my question is assuming that we cannot do that with the opinion of Rabbeinu Tam.]

Comment: Just FYI I also read (significant parts of) that book, and while he is very confident in what he wrote, not everyone agrees with his conclusions. So just take any "feelings of being convinced" with a grain of salt. Lots of good information and background and analysis, just I (and others) think the sugya isn't actually as "smooth" as he presents.

Comment: Not everyone discards Rabbeinu Tam's position: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8778

Comment: @Fred For sure they don't. But I included in my question, *Assuming*... I'm asking what to do if the question of מציאות is settled.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd be interested hearing which points you think are unclear. I had several of my own, but I don't know that much about the sugya.

Comment: @Micho On one foot, I encourage you to consider the possibility that the gra is right that "tzet" from pesachim is not "tzet" from shabbat and at the same time Rabbenu Tam is right that "shkiya" from psachim not the same as "mishetishka" from shabbat, ie the entire split of everyone must be either gra or RT is a false dichotomy. Also consider that the geonim (or the gemara) may not have used the word sunset in the modern scientific sense. Finally, think twice if a super expert seeing three stars using tricks like lining up where you know it will be and staring is the intended metric for night.

Comment: A full review is obviously beyond the scope of these comments, especially because nearly any detail becomes very nitty gritty very fast (that's part of what is impressive about the book being written to target a more general audience).

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you. I was always interested in the take of some acharonim that sounded like (a) Of course I hold like R"T, and (b) We wait 50 minutes (or whatever) after sunset. It really sounded to me like some held that the R"T's time began before official sunset. I wasn't sure how that worked, but I was uncomfortable with the Mishnah Berurah's insistence that there is only one choice for "shkiah", when the sun disappears below the horizon.

Comment: @DoubleAA That was an interesting section, on how soon one can see stars. One detail he basically skipped was, What does "three medium-sized stars" mean? He just throws out in passing that big stars = planets, medium-sized = the very brightest true stars. Does everyone agree to that?

Comment: Happy to chat more about this, but this comment thread is not the right place @MichoelR

Comment: @DoubleAA Let me know how, then, please. My email is in my profile if that helps.

Comment: @MichoelR please make it into a chat rather than going to email as I would very much like to follow along as would others

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Not having a Sanhedrin means the psak of the Shulchan Aruch is not binding either. If the majority of poskim say not to follow his opinion, we don't.

Comment: @N.T. if the majority of poskim say not to follow the gemara, we also don't. We always follow poskim. The question is seemingly more about when a posek would not rule like a significant written precedent.

Comment: @MichoelR click this https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new, once done and have a link, come back here to share the link